# How can I include commit hash in the installation of a package from Github repository?

Tags: git

I need to install a certain package. This is how I install right now:
`git+https://[TOKEN]@github.com/Organization/magneton-core#egg=magneton`

Now, I have been asked to include the commit hash which is `36a1370845b7fd769cb558e5c4bc972ed865b804`. What changes do I need to make?

Comment: What do you mean by "installation"? Are you using Git submodules? Or maybe (based on `#egg=` in your URL) Python's `pip`?

Comment: Also where exactly do you need the hash?